# symfony 4 autowiring false not work for specific service

Tags: service, autowired, symfony4

I don't understand this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Service\PdfLatexManager": argument "$binary" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly

service.yaml:

```
parameters

rubber-pipe: '/usr/bin/rubber-pipe'

services:

_defaults:
    autowire: true      
    autoconfigure: true 
    public: false     

App\Service\PdfLatexManager:
    autoconfigure: false
    autowire: false
    public: true
    class: "%pdfLatex_class%"
    arguments: ["%rubber-pipe%", "@service_container"]
```

my service class:

```
namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PdfLatexManager extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Full system path to rubber-pipe binary
     * @var string
     */
    protected $binary;
...
 public function __construct($binary, ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->binary = $binary;
    $this->container = $container;
}

...
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks
Cédric

Comment: Can you post your service class ?

Comment: my service class is added

Comment: I created a symfony project with your informations, i don't have any problem.  Your parameter rubber-pipe is defined ? And why do you specify class in your service declaration ?

Comment: yes: rubber-pipe: '/usr/bin/rubber-pipe' . I have removed class (old test), but not change...

Comment: And why your class herit from AbstractController ?

Comment: For access to render function. I have removed AbastractController and i have same error...